# posting JSON object with jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object:

```
var formData = {"field1":field1, "oper1":oper1, "value1":value1, "field2":field2, "oper2":oper2, "value2":value2, "field3":field3, "oper3":oper3, "value3":value3};
```

and I'm trying to post it with

```
$.post("<%=request.getRequestURL().toString()%>getXML.jsp", formData, function(response){getXML(response)});
```

I need the post to be formData = {json object} so I can get it from the request object with request.getParameter("formData").

However, everything is being posted by each key:value in the request, so I can't get the object by the formData name. I've tried stringifying the object and changing formData to {"formData":formData}in the jquery call, but nothing seems to be working. {"formData":formData} puts the parameters in this format:

```
formData[field1]    lname
formData[field2]    fname
formData[field3]    title
formData[oper1]     contain
formData[oper2]     contain
formData[oper3]     contain
formData[value1]    smith
formData[value2]    
formData[value3]
```

Is there a way to pass the object as the variable name "formData"?

Comment: Tried just wrapping the data e.g. `{formData: formData}` ?

Comment: Yes. It gives the same output as {"formData":formData}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem by using:

```
$.post("<%=request.getRequestURL().toString()%>getXML.jsp", {"formData":JSON.stringify(formData)}, function(response){getXML(response)});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use an relevant `Model` object that holds the `json` as a sting. After that you may `post` the  `model` object.